# How can I set Excel file column widths in a for loop when exporting multiple sheets from a DataFrame?

Tags: python, excel

Need help setting Excel file column widths when using a for loop and unique sheet names.

Here is sample data with the code that works without setting the column widths ...

```
cols=['Types', 'Teeth']

df_CANs = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Types": ['1B27', '3D59', '3D59', '1B27', '2C88', '4B42', '4B42'],
    "Teeth": [45, 33, 38, 42, 27, 41, 45],})

for Types in df_CANs['Types'].unique().tolist():
    df_CANs[df_CANs['Types']==Types][cols].to_excel(Types[-3:]+'.xlsx',sheet_name= (Types[-3:]), index=False)
```

Here is what I have learned on this site ... and it works as well, but only on an individual file basis. When I try to incorporate this code into my original code, with the for loop, the result is my last file has no data but the correct column widths.

```
df_CANs = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Types": ['1B27', '3D59', '3D59', '1B27', '2C88', '4B42', '4B42'],
    "Teeth": [45, 33, 38, 42, 27, 41, 45],})


writer = pd.ExcelWriter("sample_data.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter",)
df_CANs.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1", index=False)

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets["Sheet1"]

worksheet.set_column(0, 0, 18)
worksheet.set_column(1, 1, 22)

writer.close()
```